# Are 'unmatched' and 'unparalleled' always interchangeable?

Tags: word-choice, difference

Their definitions seems to be the same, and both are said to be formal. Is there any difference between them?

> [unmatched](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/unmatched): having no equal; better than any other of the same type

> [unparalleled](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/unparalleled): having no equal; better or greater than any other

Comment: I don't think there is. My instinct is that _unmatched_ is followed with _by any other_ more often than _unparalleled_ is, but I can't find evidence to back that up.

Comment: The word "Unmatched" is used more commonly than the word "unparalleled".

Comment: They're not always interchangeable: unmatched has additional meanings (you could use it of an odd sock or maybe even an unmarried person). You should [consult multiple dictionaries](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unmatched) to get a better idea of how a word is used.

Comment: Both mean that two things are equal, but there might be a tiny difference in the **way** that that equality is determined. *Unparalleled* suggests that one places them side-by-side for comparison. *Unmatched* can suggest imagining a competition between the two things, and that they both reach the same objective. In ordinary use, though, there is no difference between the terms. Would you prefer this, or a simple “no” answer?

Comment: Most definitely not in Geometry, most likely not in common English.

Answer (score 1):

When you're describing something that has no equal or is beyond comparison in conversational English, unmatched and unparalleled mean the same thing and can be interchanged.

However, the two words don't always have this meaning. As others pointed out, you might use **unmatched** to describe socks that don't make a pair, and in geometry, parallel means something very specific.

So, for all intents and purposes, the answer to your question is Yes, unless that's not the intended meaning of the word.